# Firefox not send extension disabled status?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

when firefox extension is active, following SDK script sends me active status of the extension. here is the script...

```
worker.port.on("getAddonStatus", function( data ) {
    var addonStatus = [];
    AddonManager.getAddonByID( "jid1-Ek4rsiwaZyfJnw@jetpack" , function(addons){
        //alert('addon script');
        if ( !addons ) {
            addonStatus.push({
                    status : 'failure',
                    id: '',
                    appDisabled: '',
            });
        } else {
            addonStatus.push({
                    status : 'success',
                    id: addons.id,
                    appDisabled: addons.appDisabled,
            });
        }
        worker.port.emit( "addonStatus", addonStatus );
    });
});
```

why is not send me any response when firefox extension is disabled? please help me...

Answer (score 0):

When your restartless/jetpack add-on is not enabled, it is not running either, simple as that. I.e your code that would perform the `AddonManager.getAddonByID` call is not running either.